# heroku-deployed application not secure

Tags: heroku, deployment, dns, namecheap

I have a deployed heroku app, https://myapp.herokuapp.com/, to which I want to link my custom domain, myapp.com, from namecheap. So I did the following:

1. Add myapp.com as a domain in heroku settings.
2. Add a CNAME record for my deployed heroku app in namecheap:

> Type: CNAME Record, Host: @, Value: myapp.herokuapp.com., TTL: 1 min

At this point, my app worked at myapp.com. The problem is, the connection was not secure - the app ran at http://myapp.com/. I noticed that you need a paid heroku account to use their SSL services, so I upgraded my account to Hobby. I then configured the SSL to "automatic", and refreshed domain status. Heroku thereby changed to

> Your app can be found at https://myapp.com

The problem is, when I click on the link heroku gave me, chrome redirects me to a warning page, saying my connection is not secure [image]

and that the heroku ssl certificate is invalid. Why does this happen? Is it a problem with heroku or with my namecheap domain?

My full namecheap DNS records for reference:

> Type: CNAME Record, Host: @, Value: myapp.herokuapp.com., TTL: 1 min
>
> Type: CNAME Record, Host: www, Value: myapp.herokuapp.com., TTL: 1 min
>
> Type: URL Redirect Record, Host: @, Value: https://www.myapp.com., unmasked

Answer (score 0):

The issue is https.

You have to force the files to be loaded via https on production.

Using php laravel, in your AppServiceProvider, add the following to the boot method

```
public function boot() 
{
    if ($this->app->environment('production')) {
        URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
}
```